# Custom adapter with editText and Check Box and TextView

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, custom-adapter, listview-adapter

i got stuck in a adapter for listview :
 I have a textView(Name) , checkbox, editText(quantity of name) in adapter .
 Default editText will be disable but when i check any checkbox then only i will    be able to enter quantity .
 in getView I was to stuck to code that thing. and in OnItemClick of listview i need to store the Model object and store on DataBase .

```
package com.example.lokesh.agrigate.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.lokesh.agrigate.R;
import com.example.lokesh.agrigate.models.Crop;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Amit on 2015-10-10.
 */
public class CropListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    List<Integer> positions;
    List<Crop> mCrops;
    public CropListViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Crop> mCrops) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mCrops = mCrops;
        mSelectedList=new HashMap<>();
        positions=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    Map<Crop,Integer> mSelectedList=null;



    public void addCrop(List<Crop> crops){
        this.mCrops=crops;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCrops.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Crop getItem(int position) {
        return mCrops.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Crop crop=getItem(position);
        Holder mHolder=null;
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.crop_list_item,null);
            mHolder=new Holder();
            convertView.setTag(mHolder);

            mHolder.mName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crpname);
            mHolder.mHelpText=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantityHelpText);
            mHolder.mCheckox=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkCrop);
            mHolder.mQuantityEditText=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);

            mHolder.mQuantityEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });

            mHolder.mCheckox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (int) buttonView.getTag();
                    if (isChecked) {


                    } else {

                    }
                    buttonView.setChecked(isChecked);
                }
            });


        }else{
            mHolder=(Holder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        mHolder.mCheckox.setTag(position);
        mHolder.mName.setText(crop.toString());

        return convertView;
    }

    public void setData(List<Crop> crops) {
        this.mCrops=crops;
    }


    class Holder{
        TextView mName;
        TextView mHelpText;
        CheckBox mCheckox;
        EditText mQuantityEditText;


    }
}
```

Activity OnItemClick :

```
Map<Crop,Integer> data=new HashMap<>();
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onCropItemClickListener=new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkCrop);
        Crop crop=(Crop)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        if(checkBox.isChecked()){

            EditText ed=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(ed.getText().toString()))
              data.put(crop,Integer.parseInt(ed.getText().toString()));
        }else{
           data.remove(crop);
        }
    }
};
```

Please help me to correct the adapter and OnItemClick :

Comment: You have to check for the checkbox in getview if checkbox is checked then you have to use setEnable method to true for edittext to be enabled.

Comment: @Clairvoyant : Yes i want to do that but not able to do it correctly , If you had any similar code then please share .

Comment: You have left empty ur **setOnCheckedChangeListener** why dont you write setenabled method line in if else logic

Answer (score 0):

Enable the edit text in the setOnCheckedChangeListener block.

```
        mHolder.mCheckox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
              mHolder.mQuantityEditText(true)
                } else {
                   mHolder.mQuantityEditText(false)
                }
                buttonView.setChecked(isChecked);//not sure why you doing this, required if you just want to enable/disable edit text
            }
        });
```

Comment: you can't access holder members directly from inner class unless until you make then final . If you had done similar code in past then please share it .

Comment: alternative could be have a method in your ViewHolder which would do the same operation or make the the mHolder variable a data member of your Adapter class, that way you need not make it final

Answer (score 0):

After going through lots of searches on different sites and understating the problem and correcting my code, I had created new model and used that instead of crop, check my code :

```
    mCropList=mDbAdapter.getAllCrops();
    mEmployees=mDbAdapter.getAllEmployee();
    mTransactionModels=new ArrayList<>();
    for(Crop crop: mCropList){
        TransactionModel transactionModel=new TransactionModel();
        transactionModel.setIsSelected(false);  // this is to keep track of checkbox selection
        transactionModel.setQuantity(0);  // get EditText value of quantity .
        transactionModel.setDate(date);
        transactionModel.setName(crop.getName());
        transactionModel.setId(crop.getId());
        mTransactionModels.add(transactionModel);
    }



mCropListViewAdapter=new CropListViewAdapter(mContext,transactionModels);
            mCropListView.setAdapter(mCropListViewAdapter);   // Setting adapter
```

Now below is code of modified adapter :

package com.example.lokesh.agrigate.adapters;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.lokesh.agrigate.R;
import com.example.lokesh.agrigate.models.Crop;
import com.example.lokesh.agrigate.models.TransactionModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Amit on 2015-10-10.
 */
public class CropListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    List<Integer> positions;
    List<TransactionModel> mTransactionModels;
    public CropListViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<TransactionModel> mTransactionModels) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mTransactionModels = mTransactionModels;
        mSelectedList=new HashMap<>();
        positions=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    Map<Crop,Integer> mSelectedList=null;



    public void addCrop(List<TransactionModel> mTransactionModels){
        this.mTransactionModels=mTransactionModels;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTransactionModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public TransactionModel getItem(int position) {
        return mTransactionModels.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       final TransactionModel transactionModel =getItem(position);
        Holder mHolder=null;
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.crop_list_item,null);
            mHolder=new Holder();
            convertView.setTag(mHolder);

            mHolder.mName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crpname);
            mHolder.mHelpText=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantityHelpText);
            mHolder.mCheckox=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkCrop);
            mHolder.mQuantityEditText=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            mHolder.watcher=new MutableWatcher();
            mHolder.mQuantityEditText.addTextChangedListener(mHolder.watcher);


            mHolder.mCheckox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (int) buttonView.getTag();
                    if (isChecked) {


                        mTransactionModels.get(getPosition).setIsSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                    } else {
                        mTransactionModels.get(getPosition).setIsSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                    }


                }
            });


        }else{
            mHolder=(Holder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        mHolder.mQuantityEditText.setTag(position);


        mHolder.mCheckox.setTag(position);
        mHolder.mName.setText(transactionModel.getName().toString());
        mHolder.watcher.setActive(false);
        mHolder.mQuantityEditText.setText(mTransactionModels.get(position).getQuantity()+"");
        mHolder.watcher.setPosition(position);
        mHolder.watcher.setActive(true);
        mHolder.mCheckox.setChecked(mTransactionModels.get(position).isSelected());

        return convertView;
    }

    public void setData(List<TransactionModel> mTransactionModels) {
        this.mTransactionModels=mTransactionModels;
    }

    public List<TransactionModel> getmTransactionModels(){
        return mTransactionModels;
    }


    class Holder{
        TextView mName;
        TextView mHelpText;
        CheckBox mCheckox;
        EditText mQuantityEditText;
        MutableWatcher watcher;


    }

    class MutableWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private int mPosition;
        private boolean mActive;

        void setPosition(int position) {
            mPosition = position;
        }

        void setActive(boolean active) {
            mActive = active;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (mActive) {
                if(s.length()>0) {
                    mTransactionModels.get(mPosition).setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
                }else {

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Not a valid Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now instead of blocking Edittext for unchecked Items, I modified my check as :

```
for(TransactionModel model: models ){
                if(model.isSelected()){
                    if(model.getQuantity()<=0){
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Please enter a valid quantity",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }else{
                        model.setEmployee(mCurrentEmployee);

                        mValidModels.add(model);
                    }

                }else{
                    count++;
                }
            }
```